# How to Logic Pro Headphone Sett-Up for Sample prelistening

Tags: daw, logic-pro, audio

I am new to Logic and want to make Live Performances. I could not find anything about **setting up Headphones and Master audio split**. I want to hear the Samples preview on my headphones and the track on the master to the speakers from the stage.
If there would be a possibility to also prelisten some tracks, I would like to hear about it.

I’m grateful for any advice or hints.

Greetings Tree

Comment: Sounds to me like you bought the wrong software. Mainstage is designed for live work, though it sounds more like you need some kind of DJ software.